# python how to parse css file as key value

Tags: python, css, parsing

I have a css like a:

```
body, html { aaa: aaa }
h1, h2 { bbb: bbb; }
h3, h4, h5 { ccc: ccc; }
```

and i want to parse this string and get an ordered dict / or something like:

```
{
    'body, html': 'aaa: aaa',
    'h1, h2':  'bbb: bbb;',
    'h3, h4, h5': 'ccc: ccc;'
}
```

I want to know all selectors and their properties

anybody knows any python library for accomplish this?

thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/Kozea/tinycss2 this library is useful

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would suggest to use the [`cssutils`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cssutils/) module.

```
import cssutils
from pprint import pprint

css = u'''
body, html { color: blue }
h1, h2 { font-size: 1.5em; color: red}
h3, h4, h5 { font-size: small; }
'''

dct = {}
sheet = cssutils.parseString(css)

for rule in sheet:
    selector = rule.selectorText
    styles = rule.style.cssText
    dct[selector] = styles


pprint(dct)
```

Output:

```
{u'body, html': u'color: blue',
 u'h1, h2': u'font-size: 1.5em;\ncolor: red',
 u'h3, h4, h5': u'font-size: small'}
```

In your question you asked for a key/value representation. But if you do want to access the individial selectors or proprties, use `rule.selectorList` and iterate over its properties for `rule.style`:

```
for property in rule.style:
    name = property.name    
    value = property.value
```

Comment: I ran into some issues with comments and other returned rules for some more complex CSS. Hopefully this saves someone a little time to only return the style rules.

`ignored_rules = [
        cssutils.css.csscomment.CSSComment,
        cssutils.css.cssfontfacerule.CSSFontFaceRule,
        cssutils.css.cssmediarule.CSSMediaRule,
        cssutils.css.cssunknownrule.CSSUnknownRule,
    ]
    for rule in sheet:
        if any((isinstance(rule, rule_type) for rule_type in ignored_rules)):
            continue
        selector = rule.selectorText`